# Why "go list -m all" returns more modules than those required in go.mod?

Tags: go, go-modules

I have a simple module that requires only one external module, **github.com/spf13/viper v1.15.0**.

The **go.mod** file of my module is the following

module github.com/me/mymodule

```
go 1.20

require github.com/spf13/viper v1.15.0

require (
    github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.6.0 // indirect
    github.com/hashicorp/hcl v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/magiconair/properties v1.8.7 // indirect
    github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure v1.5.0 // indirect
    github.com/pelletier/go-toml/v2 v2.0.6 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/afero v1.9.3 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/cast v1.5.0 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/jwalterweatherman v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5 // indirect
    github.com/subosito/gotenv v1.4.2 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.3.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.5.0 // indirect
    gopkg.in/ini.v1 v1.67.0 // indirect
    gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1 // indirect
)
```

If I run the command `go list -m all` I get a much longer list of modules, e.g. containing

```
cloud.google.com/go v0.105.0
cloud.google.com/go/bigquery v1.8.0
cloud.google.com/go/compute v1.14.0
cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata v0.2.3
cloud.google.com/go/datastore v1.1.0
cloud.google.com/go/firestore v1.9.0
cloud.google.com/go/longrunning v0.3.0
cloud.google.com/go/pubsub v1.3.1
cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.14.0
```

This clearly means that the **go.mod** requirements are not the full [build list](https://go.dev/ref/mod#glos-build-list).

Which is the reason for this difference?

By the way, I picked some of the modules which are in the build list and asked, for instance,

```
go mod why -m cloud.google.com/go
```

and got the answer

```
main module does not need module cloud.google.com/go
```

Answer (score 0):

Because many packages have other dependencies, so in order for these packages imported in the go.mod file to work, they must also be imported

Comment: I think this what indirect requirements are, but they are already i go.mod, marked as indirect